# How to store data inside a CSV file using filehelpers?

Tags: c#, .net, csv, filehelpers

I searched around and everyone kept saying the best way to handle CSV files in C# is Filehelpers. But I keep looking and I can't find a comprehensive guide as of how to append a csv file. I have this class:

```
class FlashCard
{
    public static string Front { get; private set; }
    public static string Back { get; private set; }
    public static Difficulty CardDifficulty { get; private set; }
    public enum Difficulty
    {
        easy,
        medium,
        hard,
        very
    }
    public void Flashcard(string front, string back, Difficulty Difficulty )
    {
        Front = front;
        Back = back;
        CardDifficulty = Difficulty; 
    }


}
```

And I want to save instances of it inside a CSV file. But how?

Comment: You can use Linq2Csv library, this has a comprehensive list of features for handling csv files. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25133/LINQ-to-CSV-library

Comment: You can either create the csv format by hand yourself following the csv schema/standard or use a library/framework that can do it for you. you can search online for libraries that do this. CsvHelper is one that I am aware of.

Answer (score 2):

You have to have already a csv file, then you can easily convert this file to your entities (like FlashCards).

Take a look on quick start http://www.filehelpers.net/quickstart/

First of all you have to mark your class with attribute [DelimitedRecord(",")]

Answer (score 0):

To write a CSV file from your class using FileHelpers, map your class to a 'spec' class which describes the CSV file. Something like this.

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
public class FlashCardCsvRow
{
     public string Front;
     public string Back;
     public string CardDifficulty;
}

var flashcards = new List<FlashCard>(); // your class above
// populate flashcards however you like

var csvRows = flashCards.Select(x =>
  new FlashCardCsvRow() 
     {
         Front = x.Front,
         Back = x.Back,
         CardDifficulty = x.CardDifficulty.ToString();
     });

var engine = new FileHelperEngine<FlashCardCsvRow>();
engine.WriteFile("Output.Txt", csvRows);
```

FileHelpers has lots of nice features to help you further. For instance you might want to implement [your own enum converter](http://www.filehelpers.net/example/Converters/CustomConverter/) instead of using `x.CardDifficulty.ToString()`.

By the way, you'll run into trouble with your `static` properties in `FlashCard`. I'm not sure you meant to make those properties static.